# Is it acceptable to promote your own blog?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising, self-promotion, blog

In Stack Overflow question *[Create function from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279946/create-function-from-code)*, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279946/create-function-from-code/26288453#26288453) has a link to the user's blog; in which it duplicates the Stack Overflow question and provides a fuller answer. This seems to be piggybacking off Stack Overflow page rank reputation to promote their own site.

The answer given is an acceptable answer, so should this be flagged as spam or is it OK?

A further question is, can someone copy and paste Stack Overflow questions into their own blog?

Comment: Meh, I'm guessing that the poster correctly identified this to be a homework question.  He's an MVP, he knows the ropes.  It is not supposed to make a difference, but let's not kid ourselves.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Should this be flagged as spam or is it ok?

Is this an isolated case for the user? Do they disclose that the link is to their own blog?

If so, move on. Not a problem.

When someone posts a link to their blog for a longer/larger/more comprehensive discussion of their own answer (or even an answer by someone else), where the blog completely answers the question though it isn't required by the answer (that is, the answer stands by itself - so if the blog 404s, it still makes sense), that's not a problem by itself.

If someone *always* links to their blog, on every post, then no, that's not OK. In particular if the blog isn't directly answering the question and is blatantly self promotional.

Comment: That's the biggest tip-off right there - lots of links that are at _best_ tangentially related to the question at hand, or answers that just try to change the subject in order for the link to make more sense.

Comment: Why does it make a difference if they "always" do it or not? Either the answer provided (with link to blog post) is good (in which case, the more the better), or it's bad (in which case they should all be downvoted). Why is a few ok but lots bad?

Comment: So if we encounter an user promoting his blog in every post he made do we edit or flag ?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not acceptable to promote your own blog. By that I mean where all or almost all of your answers are just linking to your blog. The occasional answer that links to your blog is OK.

You can, however, provide an answer that you've previously published on your blog as long as you include *the relevant parts* of the answer in the answer and the link is just for reference. The answer should be able to stand on it's own without the link being present.

You should apply the following rule of thumb:

> A single answer that just links to a blog is just a bad answer. Down-vote, edit, comment as appropriate.
>
> Multiple answers that just link to a blog are spam. Flag as such.

As for your followup question:

> A further question is, can someone copy and paste SO questions into their own blog?

Yes you can copy Stack Overflow questions as long as you follow the attribution rules. Which are basically:

1. Link back to the original question.
2. Acknowledge the original author (with a link back to their profile for example).
3. Don't try to pass it off as your own work.

The attribution rules are linked at the foot of every page:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rule is that the answer needs to be complete enough to stand alone, not that the entire blog post/series addressing the issue needs to be placed in the answer.  So "include *all* of the answer in the answer" isn't really the criterion.

Comment: as @oded says: *If someone always links to their blog, on every post, then no, that's not OK.*, I'm wondering. What if you have a blog(or normal website) and on that website you just post really good workarounds or examples of things. What if a lot of the questions on SO can be answered by something you posted on that website. Would it be acceptable if you answer a lot of questions like so: Try this: (code with explanation) and then after that a link to your website as reference? If all your answers would be like this, is it acceptable?

Comment: I find this answer to be too much of a sweeping generalization. -1 I hope to see this answer improved in a way that's highlighting the differences between "Link-only answer" and "Good answer with link to further information" Because an answer is not bad just because it links to a blog....