# Is it OK to ask and answer your own questions and link to your wiki?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer, self-promotion

This question will be probably controversal, so please keep in mind that it is meant for discussion in the first place.

I am currently thinking about writing a FAQ or "best practices" on a specific area.

> For those interested in the context: I am the author of a Maven plugin for XML Schema -> Java compilation. I'm doing it ~8 years already and have extensive experience on this subject. I compiled a huge number of schemas, know ins and outs, bugs and workarounds, contributed a number of fixes to Sun/Oracle. Also answer a lot of question on the subject on SO.

I could just write this FAQ it in a wiki/blog. My projects are (now mostly) on GitHub, so I could just add it to the wiki there.

But then I thought, StackOverflow might be a good place to make it public. As I read here, [it is OK or even encouraged to ask and answer your own questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):

> So …
>
> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.

This is surely fine and good. If I do this, a lot of people would be able to profit from it. To make it clear:

- My goal is to formulate/write down answers to typical questions on the subject.
- I want to provide value content, no trivial stuff.
- Most of these questions were (probably) already asked on SO. I don't want to reuse these questions because:

  - I'll have search and manually pick them.
  - People often ask a question for their specific case. Which is different from well-formulated question on the abstract, generic level. It takes effort to move to that abstract level which would be easier transferrable between specific use cases. I am willing to provide this effort.

So I think it would be good to make a FAQ in SO.

*(Now comes the tricky part.)*

However, I would *also* like to keep my FAQ/Best practices in my GitHub wiki.

Main reason that it is actually a part of the documentation for the tool I develop.

Another reason - I'll be open about it - is that I'd like to attract people to my GitHub project. GitHub gives an opportunity to see that people use what I do (via "stars", for instance), it helps to stay motivated. I don't monetize on the project, I just would appreciate feedback and a bit of (I am not sure if it is the right word) appraisal. I hope for your understanding.

But somehow my gut feeling says that it might be not OK. I saw the discussions on "[is it OK to promote your blog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog)" - somewhat controversal. I am not sure, I'd be grateful if you could help me to set my mind with this.

So what would you think, if you'd see someone:

- Ask a well-formulated question.
- Provide a hopefully good answer to his own question.
- Links to the entry in the wiki.

---

Relevant questions:

- [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: See [How can I link to an external resource in a community friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

Comment: See also [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good pointer thank you. I would meet the criteria. The peculiarity is: I want to ask and answer these questions myself.

Comment: Your questions still need to be on-topic.  Other than that, there is no difference.