# User gratuitously links to own website in otherwise good answers

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

*This question is different from "[Is it acceptable to promote your own blog?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog)" in that the user's answers themselves are great material and most definitely **not** spam — it's just that last bit with the gratuitous link I have an issue with. This is a case not addressed in that previous question.*

---

I'm seeing this user link to their own website in some of their answers (not a majority, but often enough). The link is not to a specific blog post dealing with the specific issue at hand (that would be fine) but rather to their front page, a bit like this:

> You can bingle the jiggyjag by krutzwalding the woosh like this:
>
> *[...good answer content...]*
>
> More info available @ [mywebsite.com](http://link)

The answer itself is great, the website is just fine as well — there is, as promised, "more info", in the form of blog posts on a general variety of issues mostly related to the programming language in question.

But I don't see how the link relates to the answer. To me this is a gratuitous link whose sole apparent purpose is to generate traffic and hits. I feel like removing it. In fact, I feel like removing *all* similar links from that user's answers — and other users' answers if encountered in the future.

Should the links be removed?

Comment: Sounds like spam. Flagging is the appropriate response.

Comment: Oded's answer says "If someone always links to their blog, on every post, then no, that's not OK. In particular if the blog isn't directly answering the question and is blatantly self promotional." But it's hard for me to say for certain seeing a generalized version. I'm sure others will have their opinions as well.

Comment: If the link isn't appropriate to the question or answer, then the link is a tagline, and can be removed.  If the link contains information directly relating to the question and answer, then no, it's fine.  If the user seems to be abusing this, then flag and let the mods know, providing links to examples of egregious linking.  Then move on.