# Edit that removed self-promotion rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, self-promotion

While doing Triage, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974489/how-to-get-text-from-edittext/29531272) that already had four answers, one accepted and others saying the same thing. The [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29531272/1270789) was an obvious cut'n'paste from somewhere else (note the variables differ), followed by a link to the top page of the poster's own blog.

I downvoted, and also edited out the URL (it doesn't go anywhere useful) but [got it rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7623734) as "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post". This question suggests [I should flag as spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog) (only?), especially as I noticed the user has done the same thing three other times (which I down-voted and notified a mod), but in this case the URL didn't even point to a post, just the top-level domain.

So, should I have edited the answer and put the link to the correct blog spam, or just left as-is and waited for the mods to process my flag?

Comment: Ugh, I sure hope you didn't find a question from 2009 in the Triage queue.  Are you sure this wasn't an entry in the First Posts queue?  If you know that it is project spam then just flag it like that.

Comment: Oops, it would have been First Post or Late Answer then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, the advice for spam is not to edit it out; it is easier for the moderators if they can see right away that something is spam, and don't have to delve into the edit history.

In this case I would have used a custom flag, to point out that the answer was a copy-paste answer with a promotional link added.

So yes, you should have waited until your flag was handled.