# What to do with a user who promotes his site in all his answers?

Tags: discussion, spam, moderation, advertising, self-promotion

I recently down voted and flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987966/tsql-joining-two-big-tables-are-taking-lots-of-time-and-yields-lots-of-records/32988091#32988091) as VLQ (almost link-only, with no added or helpful info in the text), then checked the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2505809/laxmikant). All answers from the user are containing one or more links to the same site (the site's url is in the user's profile too).

Since some of the answers are containing useful information, I can't decide what to do with the user.

In my opinion this is advertising/spamming, but please help me how to handle it?

Note: The user deleted the linked answer after 3 down votes.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog

Comment: also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow/260641#260641

Comment: The last one helped me, thanks. Did not find it by searching for 'promotion'.

Comment: 'promotion' and 'advertising' I found some threads, but in general they said, that check all posts and down vote/flag them if necessary. Ofc it is possible, that I failed to notice/open the one linked here.

Comment: This question is useful as a search target for the words you used. No harm done. I'm a regular spam hunter so I know where to look for and how things are called.