# What to do when particular user is sharing his own site's link in every answer?

Tags: discussion

Sorry for taking this point but I saw a guy is sharing his own blog/site's link under every answer of his, whether it is related to answer or not. I think he wants some traffic, but this is not good. When I asked him why you are sharing, he said this is my own blog where you can read but then the other issue is that when his blog/site will be closed, then these answers with links won't be helpful.

Question where he put his thought by saying yes he will [promote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261020/what-is-the-best-way-for-designing-responsive-layout/36261151?noredirect=1#comment60150744_36261151) his site.

See example :
 [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148711/enable-table-in-wordpress/36171207#36171207)
 [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081947/toggle-an-animation-over-an-element-of-a-grid-and-fadein-out-the-other-elements/36083146#36083146)
 [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260398/navbar-right-is-not-working-on-list/36260622#36260622)
 [Four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257417/image-position-slide-in-menu/36257749#36257749)
 [Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215488/need-to-fix-right-border-and-should-be-middle-aligned-of-the-content/36215785#36215785)

I read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog) and found that it is not acceptable, then what can we do to remove/stop people by doing this. Yes I did flag that question but isn't there any ban or something like that so these type of user can stop doing this??(like after downvote you can't ask question so might be after few downvotes on  your answer, you can't answer or like that).

Not sure answer ban will work but something must be done for these types of user who are here to promote their site rather then to help.

Sorry if my thought are not good.

**UPDATED**
I have already added the link where i found what to do but i mentioned that fake user is getting so many downvotes(flags) still he is posting links in every answer and saying he should promote side by side then how to stop them? Mod Oded said "that's not OK", so there should be action like ban to answer or something so he can stop spamming.. M not having much knowledge of meta so if m doing any mistake by asking this then m really sorry.. Just wanted to help to make SO better and better...

**I am not asking to suspend this particular user**, but people who are doing this as there should be a way. I don't have any issue with user and to create way by this we can specify and stop these kinds of things.. Sorry if anyone hurts by my lines..that wasn't my moto or aim to suspend or downvote any user. We all are on SO for help and to make world easier for future/current user of SO or one who wants to learn after trying.

Thank you

Comment: I already added this answer's link in my example.. i requested how to stop these guyz..

Comment: Yes, I wondered why it popped up as the very first suggestion (which is (alas) extremely rare) and so I re-read your question with some more attention ...

Comment: As a side note- It seems that the user under discussion is receiving some downvotes (Meta effect)- please refrain from donwvoting his answers just because he linked his blog- I'm sure his intentions weren't malicious. Answers should be judged by their content- not by the person posting them. It seems to me like his answers are helpful in general. There is no need to discourage him from contributing to the site just because he made a mistake.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, no he did not receive downvote after meta effect.. he got downvotes before i post on meta and sorry but m not targeting particular user that's why i added these types of users. Even he mentioned that yes he will promote side by side..  Hope you will get my point. Thank you

Comment: `but then the other issue is that when his blog/site will be closed, then these answers with links won't be helpful.` He is not posting link only answers, he is just adding a signature type of thing to his answer.

Comment: Please follow that question in which he mentioned that user can read basic things from here. He said this when i added link of site which are quite basics. I don't have issue with user but way he present the answer. and one user should not add his blog's link in every post for personal profit..this was my first question. please check back.

Comment: And yup.. Meta effect, now m getting downvote of my question which i asked years ago when i did not know how to ask well question.. Thanx guyz.. Every time i'm learning from SO :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag any one of the user's posts using a custom moderator flag and describe the issue in the description of the flag (along with links to their other answers) so that moderators can handle it. It's important to write all the details in the flag's description.

*To answer your updated text:*

> i mentioned that fake user is getting so many downvotes(flags) still he is posting links in every answer and saying he should promote side by side then how to stop them? Mod Oded said "that's not OK", so there should be action like ban to answer or something so he can stop spamming.

Downvotes and flags are different, if a user gets downvoted, it doesn't imply that he is getting flagged. Only mods and employees can see the flags raised against a user.

It's not OK, that's correct. So you should flag it, to inform the mods about it. They will handle it as they deem appropriate. I would like to mention that you should not expect any visible action in response to your flag ( like a suspension being issued to the user). How the mods handle it, is upto the mods. They may or may not suspend the user. They have other options as well. They may contact the user in chat or send a mod message etc. Suspension is visible, because there is a banner displayed on the user's profile. Other actions  (such as mod messages) are not visible to regular users.

Still, if you have any further concerns, you can write in to SE directly using the "Contact Us" link (present at the bottom of every page) and describing your concern. Again, you may (or may not) see a visible action being taken as a result of your email.

Comment: thanx for the answer, as i mentioned i already flagged with message but when i saw that user's history i found he is doing from so many months even some of user downvote the answer still he is posting which is not good so i posted here..

Comment: Thank you for more info. and now let me clear, i DONT want to suspend that user or having any issue with that  user but i don't like the way he is posting/promoting his site's link on SO. SO is not for publicity but help as if we won't stop then everyone will be selfish and will share info/answer with links and then SO's main purpose will be far away rather then being promotional site. Hope you will get my point.

Comment: I do get your point @Leothelion. I understand that you don't want someone to be suspended, but suspension is a visible action, other actions taken by mods and employees are not visible to regular users. In my answer, I mean to say that _do not_ expect a visible action. As you have already flagged the user, it means the mods know about it and will have taken the appropriate course of action. There is nothing more we need to do after flagging.

Comment: oh..yup let leave on mods.. thank you for your time and answer.. :)